# How do i extract request parameters for my webhook call for actions on google (WebAPI)

Tags: asp.net-web-api2, actions-on-google, dialogflow-es

I wanted to implement a webAPI(MVC) to act as a webhook for dialogflow, for actions on google home, which can intercept the input request and sends an appropriate response via API. I have enabled a webhook in Dialogflow.I'm using **ngrok** to simulate my local url as public. When I use the simulator in actions on google, it hits my API but, the question is how do I get my request parameters.I have created a C# object based on the json payload that i see in request tab of the simulator which is

```js
{
  "user": {
    "userId": "ABwppHFVbJd56p8i5HGFAGVEXJuHlYSZoiJIxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx",
    "locale": "en-US",
    "lastSeen": "2018-06-11T11:50:56Z"
  },
  "conversation": {
    "conversationId": "1528724450138",
    "type": "ACTIVE",
    "conversationToken": "[]"
  },
  "inputs": [
    {
      "intent": "actions.intent.TEXT",
      "rawInputs": [
        {
          "inputType": "KEYBOARD",
          "query": "Talk to papu"
        }
      ],
      "arguments": [
        {
          "name": "text",
          "rawText": "Talk to papu",
          "textValue": "Talk to papu"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "surface": {
    "capabilities": [
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER"
      },
      {
        "name": "actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT"
      }
    ]
  },
  "isInSandbox": true
}
```

my webmethod was something like this

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Connect(AsisstantRequest req)
    {}
```

and `Request.Form.AllKeys` is also empty

And also i could not find any, is there a sdk avilable for .net ?

Answer (score 0):

It has already been indicated that a class model exists based on the provided JSON in  the original question.

as a Web API the action should be in a `ApiController` and specify exactly where is should look for the request paraneters.

```
public class MyApiController : ApiController {
    //...

    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Connect([FromBody] AsisstantRequest request) {
        //...
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Dialogflow, then the JSON shown in the simulator isn't the same JSON that is sent to your webhook. Dialogflow uses [its own JSON protocol](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment#request) to send the parameters that are determined by the Intent. This includes the JSON sent by AoG, but there are many additional fields included.

In the Dialogflow JSON, parameters are available at `queryResult.parameters` while the JSON sent by AoG is available at `originalDetectIntentRequest`.